# Need to resize parent node and its corresponding child's

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

[image]

I am trying to resize the switch0 node and its corresponding child nodes in particular width range. in case parent having more than 10 child means it should resize its upper space without any collision between the nodes. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the children are accessible from the parent, for example if you have a list of nodes, you can give each node a list of numbers that correspond to the indices of their children in that same main list. If you have a node/link structure, you can also select all links where the source corresponds to the node itself, meaning the target is a child node.

Then, given the number of children `n` and the width range `width` you specified, redraw the circle of each child to be `width / n - margin` pixels, where `margin` is the space you want between the nodes (like 2-4 pixels?).

Hope this helps, without code I can't help you any further.